# Trouble with decode JSON + PHP

Tags: php, json

My php script gives out this string (for example) for JSON:

{"time":"0:38:01","kto":"\u00d3\u00e1\u00e8\u00e2\u00f6\u00e0 \u00c3\u00e5\u00ed\u00e5\u00f0\u00e0\u00eb\u00ee\u00e2","mess":"\u00c5\u00e4\u00e8\u00ed\u00fb\u00e9: *mm"}

jQuery code gets this string through JSON:

```
$.getJSON('chat_ajax.php?q=1',
    function(result) {
    alert('Time ' + result.time + ' Kto' + result.kto + ' Mess' + result.mess);
    });
```

Browser show:

```
0:38:01 Óáèâöà Ãåíåðàëîâ
Åäèíûé: *mm
```

How can I decode this string to cyrillic?

Try use:

```
<META http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
```

but nothing change

PHP Code:

```
 $res1=mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
   while ($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($res1)) {
       $rawArray=array('time' => @date("G:i:s", ($row1['time'] + $plus)), 'kto' => $row1[kto], 'mess' => $row1[mess]);
       $encodedArray = array_map(utf8_encode, $rawArray); 
       echo json_encode($encodedArray);
```

PHP ver 5.3.19

Comment: Try charset=utf-8, nothing change

Comment: @Akam It is not utf-8, windows-1251 is correct but it gets displayed as windows-1250

Comment: Try to encode your original PHP string as `UTF-8`, not the page. Use `utf8_encode` or `iconv`, and the manual on further details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\uXXXX` stands for **unicode** characters and in unicode `00d3` is `Ó` and so on. Unicode characters are unambigouos, so the character encoding of the page is ignored for them. You could use the correct unicode (i.e. `\u0443` for `У`) or write your script so that it outputs the real characters in Windows-1251 instead of unicode sequences.

**Update**

I see from your comment that you fetch this data from MySQL and use `json_encode()` to output it. `json_encode` only works for UTF-8 encoded data (and `d3` is `Ó` in UTF-8 as well, this is why you get the wrong unicode sequences).

So, you will have to convert all data from Windows-1251 to UTF-8 **before** passing it to `json_encode`, then everything else will work fine.

Converting:

```
$utf8Array = array_map(function($in) {
    return iconv('Windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $in);
}, $rawArray);
```

`utf8_encode` will not work because it is only useful for input in ISO-8859-1 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem when storing json datas in MySQL BDD : this solved the problem :

json_encode($json_data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) ;